# Do we ever see Klingon feet?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

I know this is a bit of a random question, but after watching a considerable amount of Star Trek, I've never seen a Klingon's foot - only their boots.  I know they probably have similar shaped feet to most humanoids, but is there any actually any visual scene containing a Klingon's foot in *any* series?

Comment: I think we see Worf's feet in sick bay in TNG 5x16, [Ethics](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ethics_(episode))

Comment: If Joss Whedon ever directs *Star Trek*, I'm sure he'll work it in.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, in the episode "[Ethics](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ethics_%28episode%29)" we see Worf's feet. Whether these are typical or abnormal is never explained but the similarity in shape and size (along with the symmetry of the bump above the fifth digit) would suggest that they are.

[image: Worf's feet]

This ties in quite nicely with the Klingon anatomical model designed by senior Trek 'Visual Effects Producer' (and Klingon expert) [Dan Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Curry).

[image]

Comment: These bumps look highly impractical, especially when wearing shoes. One of those gimmicks that don't make sense, I guess.

Comment: @larissagodzilla - if you go to the memory alpha page on klingons you'll see that their shoes are enormous and clunking

Comment: indeed they are. Worf's shoes aren't though. So I find it a bit curious how very well pronounced the ridges are. I'd have expected them to be deformed at least a bit.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla Starfleet standard issue boots in the 24th century are perfect for any species or occasion it seems.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla It's highly unlikely that the Klingon foot experience evolutionary pressure from footwear...

Comment: @Dacio: That's why I took care not to mention 'evolution' by name. They could still deform over the years, just like human feet do when wearing too small shoes.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_binding

Comment: @Richard: Exactly. I'd think the ridges would just rub off, get infected, heal and get somehow grown over by scar tissue. Especially when considering the Klingon's rejection of comfort, which surely extends to their boots.

Comment: It's also possible that Worf, because he was raised by humans, files off the toe spike kind of like how Hellboy files his horns. His adoptive parents probably did it initially to save on torn footwear and he does it now out of habit and respect to them.

Comment: Enterprise "Broken Bow" contains a scene in sick bay where Archer and Phlox get acquainted and discuss the Klingon they are transporting, Archer takes a moment to examine his feet which show no evidence of a toe spike as depicted in the illustration.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Huh, that would be odd considering how obsessed he is with Klingon culture. I mean, he even got special dispensation to alter his uniform to respect his heritage.

Comment: @harabeck Eyeh, but he's also slavishly devoted to his family. When the two intersect...