# Any short-haired, skin-head or bald Klingons out there?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

Following [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/52916/7885) and after watching entire Voyager, six seasons of The Next Generation and a few episodes from Deep Space Nine, I can't recall any short-haired, skin-head or bald Klingon.

I even have feeling, that *all* Klingons have dark long hairs, which eventually goes silver / gray once they're getting mature / old. So, are there any non like this out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bald klingons are actually pretty common, but not in TNG, Voyager or DS9

**We see this charming fellow in the reboot film Star Trek (2009)**
[image]

**General Chang from the Film "Undiscovered Country"**
[image]

**And this bald(ing) chap in a background shot in The Original Series**
[image]

---

Moving down the canon scale, we also come across hairless Klingon warriors in various trek novels

> *“What’s this offal?” the bald Klingon groused, sweeping the
>   accumulated padds and isolinear rods onto the floor. He stalked away
>   from the workstation, trampling the fruits of Picard’s labors under
>   his feet. “I should have known we wouldn’t find anything worth taking
>   on this miserable ship.”* - **TNG: Glass Empires**

and

> *A bald Klingon appeared, bowing before the Regent. The port officer was scrawny, with dark overhanging brows and a long, thin mustache
>   drooping from the corners of his mouth. "Greetings, Regent Worf, on
>   behalf of Khitomer You are cleared to maintain your current orbital
>   altitude. You may beam down to the spaceport at your convenience."*
>   **DS9 : Dark Passions**

Comment: Both those novels you edited in quotes from seem to have, how shall I put this... Really poor writing. Particularly the second one. I don't know how you've managed to read so many of them without gouging your own eyes out. And I'm still holding out for Roddenberry's ghost to strike J.J. Abrams down and declare the reboot series non-canon.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - with the novels, sometimes you've just got to grit your teeth and enjoy the story. I find it helps to visualise it as a real episode.

Comment: well the second novel is set in the mirror universe

Comment: If Roddenberry strikes Abrams down, Abrams will become more powerful than we can possibly imagine.

Answer (score 9):

Rare: I remember Klingon society to value the length of hair as a sign of strength and age (similar to a mane).

Unfortunately, I don't remember the exact episode, but it's one TNG episode where some Klingons meet with Worf on the Enterprise and start complaining/mocking him, since he's cutting his hair and wearing a Starfleet uniform.

However, there's also *General Chang* from *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*:

[image: General Chang]

Comment: I thought perhaps the Worf episode you were thinking of was Heart Of Glory but I didn't see any mention of his hair when skimming the transcript.

Answer (score 6):

[General Chang](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Chang_%28General%29), the primary antagonist from [*Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_VI:_The_Undiscovered_Country), is the most notable bald Klingon.

[image]

Worf also has fairly short hair in the early seasons of *TNG*.

EDIT: Upon further reflection, the vast majority of Klingons during *TOS* had short hair. Of course, since these Klingons were suffering from the Augment Virus, as revealed in *Enterprise*, it is debateable as to whether or not they count, as you are asking from the perspective of 24th century Klingons, not 23rd century ones.

Answer (score 4):

And now in *Star trek: Discovery* (2017-) most or all Kingons seen are bald.