# What is the spike on Klingon boots for?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Some Klingons wear boots with a spike near the toe, as seen in some episodes of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*. Is there an in-universe reason for this design? Is this for battle as an additional weapon, ritual, only style or maybe because of Klingon anatomy?

[image: Klingon Boot with Toe Spike in Hand-Drawn Red Circle]

Comment: Was expecting a picture of Sting wearing Klingon Boots. Sad...

Comment: i am sorry for you ;-(. I am no native english speaker, is there a better word to describe this then sting?

Comment: @kl78 - A *spur*, possibly?

Comment: @kl78 No, it looks like a Stinger (from a scorpion), or maybe a talon from a bird or certain types of dinosaur.

Comment: I'm tempted to close as dupe of [Do we ever see Klingon feet?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52916/do-we-ever-see-klingon-feet).

Comment: @T.J.L. - I've gone with *"bone-spur"* but I've also thrown in *"foot-talon"* just to mix things up.

Comment: Did no one think of "spike"?

Comment: @T.J.L.: You are mistaken. "Sting" most certainly can be used as a noun, and has a surprisingly large number of meanings as a noun. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sting

Comment: Clearly it's for mounting and riding wild targ.

Comment: I've read that the boots were left over from the movie Planet of the Apes. Maybe that was in the TNG Companion.

Comment: For the curious, it might be mentioned that in Klingon, a boot spike is called a **DaSpu'**. The word **pu'** is an archaic word for "spike", but in modern (24th century:ish) Klingon it means "phaser", and the modern word for "spike" is either **wIl** or **DuQwI'** (where the latter literally means "stabber").

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### As a weapon

If you're Klingon and you're going to be kicking someone in the gut, you really want to make 'em bleed!

### To conceal weapons

In [TNG: Heart of Glory](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Heart_of_Glory_(episode)), the two Klingons are shown in the brig assembling a disruptor from parts strategically hidden in their uniforms.  Some of those parts came out of those 'spurs'.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Star Trek 'Visual Effects Producer' [Dan Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Curry) drew the following sketch to demonstrate Klingon anatomy. You may wish to note that the bone spur on the Klingon foot lines up perfectly with the spur on the shoe, strongly suggesting that **a Klingon's foot-talon fits neatly into the talon on the shoe.**

[image]

Comment: Except I'm sure we've seen Worf's naked feet on the show where he didn't have the talon.

Comment: How does that go together with the screencap of Worf's feet (that you included in your [other answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52922/21137)) that show there isn't really a spur on the outside (rather just a little "lump"), while on the other hand, the "thorn" on various Klingon boots is considerably larger? Of course, it could fit, position-wise, and the "thorn" on the boots could be an additional "warrior-like" decoration, but in all, I feel the anatomy picture isn't a complete answer to this question.

Comment: There's a bit more info at http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Klingon including the makeup designer describing that bump as a "makeup appliance that looked like a horn", so the intent was indeed to have a spike.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I hypothesised that in order to fit into human-type shoes, he files down his foot horn.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - Worf is not half-human. He was raised by humans but is wholly Klingon.

Comment: Is the sketch considered canon? I assume it isn't, particularly since it appears to conflict with two separate instances of on-screen observations (TNG Episodes *Ethics* and *Heart of Glory*).

Comment: @Ellesedil - That's a very good question. What's canon is that neither Worf, nor the Klingons in Heart of Glory appear to have bone-spurs. What's not canon is *why*.

Comment: how exactly would you get the boot on over the horn? Unless you can flatten/straighten the horn (like you can fingers or toes) or the laces/zipper goes all the way down to the horn, anyone who has tried to dress an uncooperative child will tell you it won't work.

Comment: Worf doesn't have a full spike but he does have a kind of bony knob where it should be: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52922/12857

Comment: I think the talon would have to be prehensile enough to fold down while putting on the boot. If a Klingon was walking around bare footed, having the thing sticking up all the time would make it likely to get caught in underbrush. Thus, Worf's spurs might have been folded down.

Comment: The spike is under the skin. It is a bone structure similar to the cranial ridges.

Comment: @shade4159 - Except that the one in the picture clearly extrudes above the level of the skin.

Comment: @HowardMiller - Indeed. After all, it seems to function as a dewclaw.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor There's any other kind of child?

Comment: I imagine the bootspike is a bit like codpieces on human medieval armor. It corresponds to an anatomical feature, but the size of it might be a little exaggerated.

Comment: @Richard - You are referring to the sketch? I would argue that it is drawn like that to emphasize the skeletal structure. After all, the are images of Worf's feet lacking a protruding claw. Also, as PMar's answer points out, the boot-talons are detachable.

Comment: @shade4159 - If you think that I'm begrudging him the points, you might want to have a look at the [edit history](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/125762/revisions) on his answer :-)

Comment: Enterprise "Broken Bow" shows a bare Klingon foot (injured/unconscious in Phlox's sick bay) as Phlox and Archer get acquainted. The Klingon foot shows no evidence of a talon such as in the illustration.

Answer (score 0):

[about the appearance of early Klingons]
Worf: We do not discuss it with outsiders...
(Deep Space 9, season 5, episode 6 'Trials and Tribble-ations')

Perhaps the original Klingons did have the talon as part of their anatomy and it has simply been bred out of them (like how Klingons in more recent Star Treks look considerably different from their 'Original Series' counterparts).

Or it could have simply changed from a dominant, to a recessive gene, like blue eyes  (a trait that is more rare, inherited only if both parents are carriers.)

So now it is worn to honor their history, AND as an added weapon, or as a hiding spot.

In a warrior culture such as theirs it makes sense for their appearance to be multipurpose in function. See Sihk Warrior Weaponry; a culture whose appearance is both spiritual and practical wearing their weapons upon their bodies, or hidden within their clothing for ease.

https://www.discussionist.com/101623499