# Why were these Klingons wearing platform shoes in Heart of Glory?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon

In Star Trek: The Next Generation episode, Heart of Glory, the two Klingons can be seen wearing two platform shoes on both feet - is there an in-universe explanation or is it just for the actors to appear taller?

[image: Klingons]

As you can see, they also appear like masking tape is attaching them to the sole of the actor's feet.

Comment: By "studs", do you mean the [pointy spike](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125755/what-is-the-spike-on-klingon-boots-for?noredirect=1&lq=1) or are you referring to the [platform shoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_shoe)?

Comment: Platform shoes.

Comment: It's not masking tape.  (It looks more like duct tape in your screen grab, but it's neither.)  It is metal plating: http://images.propstore.com/113898.jpg

Comment: No secret compartments for hiding components of the disruptors they assemble?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the out-of-universe and in-universe reasons are identical: **the actor / character on the right is much shorter than the one on the left.**

First of all, the actor on the left has shoe soles that are not especially thick.  Here is a close-up on his feet from the very same episode:

[image]

The actor on the right is shorter than both his compatriot and Worf.  This height difference would be even greater if he were not wearing the platforms.

Out-of-universe, the Klingon pair are intended to be fearsome warriors, bred for battle.  Height helps to convey this.  In-universe, a short Klingon would experience a strong need to compensate.

I can find no official confirmation of this, but I believe it falls within the bounds of reason.

It is worth noting that the *TNG*-style Klingon costumes were designed by Robert Fletcher, who based the uniform on Japanese feudal warriors (as detailed in **Reeves-Stevens, Judith and Garfield (1995), *The Art of Star Trek*, Pocket Books)**. There does not seem to be a specific inspiration for the footwear.

By the way, the boots don't have masking / duct tape.  It is metal plating, as seen in the clip above but also here:

[image]

**Long story made short:** I believe the thickness of the platform is tailored to the actor, and is used in-universe to nurture an intimidating pose.

Comment: :-(... I was hoping for some side effect of the Infinite Improbability Drive